# Ifstream.open() fails after a couple iterations

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ifstream, eclipse-luna

I'm new the Ubuntu enviornment and I've also never used eclipse before.
So I'm trying to do a very simple task of just opening a file to read. I developed this on my mac in xcode and it works but when I put it through eclipse it fails.

I am calling this function continuously in order to simulate a state change like if someone pressed a button. The code is:

```
int event = 0;

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("StatusFiles/currentEvent.txt");      //Crashes here after a couple times

if(inFile)
{
    inFile >> event;
    inFile.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "StatusFiles/currentEvent.txt Not Found" << endl;
}
```

Very simple and the code is very common in order to open files in C++. There isn't a permission issues and I've included all the libraries I needed and I have the correct path.

**I can read from the file a few times, but after two or three reads when i call this function, the code fails**

The line it fails on line #2 is when I try to open the file. Eclipse yells at me saying:

**No source available for "std::basic_ifstream>::open() at 0xb8f83982**

This literally makes no sense to me and I would very much like some help!

--
Thanks

Comment: "No source available" is not the real error you're getting.  Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: I dont actually know the error because that's all eclipse gives me. If i drill down further into the call stack, it just gives me the breaking point to some low level c file

Comment: Unfortunately that exact code, alone, will never crash on that line.  Some code elsewhere is doing something *bad*.

Comment: i figured, i've used this code forever (as i'm sure everyone else has) and I can't see where or why it f's up